# WSL responds on every command "WSL is finishing upgrading... Update failed (exit code: 1603)" on Windows 11

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I have turned on my PC and tried to start Docker Desktop. Unfortunately, there was an error with WSL:

```
Docker Desktop - Unexpected WSL error

An unexpected error was encountered while executing a WSL command. Common causes include access rights issues, which occur after waking the computer or not being connected to your domain/active directory.

Please try shutting WSL down (wsl --shutdown) and/or rebooting your computer. If not sufficient, WSL may need to be reinstalled fully. As a last resort, try to install/reinstall Docker Desktop. If the issue persists please collect diagnostics and submit an issue.
```

After trying to start command `wsl --shutdown` there is shown in cmd.exe:

```
WSL is finishing an upgrade...
Update failed (exit code: 1603).
Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/E_ABORT
```

Changing rights (from user to administator) has no effect. Rebooting PC or reinstalling Docker desktop has no effect. I've tried to reinstall WSL completely (with all services of virtual machine), but after all steps of installing I came back to this message.

I was expecting for starting Docker desktop correctly

Windows version: Windows 11 Home Single Language 22621.2715

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this issue? I am having the exact same problem. It happened randomly after restarting my pc.

Comment: @kamza, the problem was solved with downgrading wsl version and fixing registry. You can find the solution in wsl github repository

Comment: WSL broke with this error installing today's (2023-11-20) Windows Updates, which broke Docker Desktop, which stops me from working on problems acceptable to SO. Finally fixed by using (on Windows 10) Settings->Apps & Features to uninstall Windows Subsystem for Linux AND Windows Subsystem for Linux Update; then rebooting; then following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual . You will need to follow the link about re-installing the WSL Update (kernel update) and install that too. Data in the Linux partition seems to have been preserved, but don't rely on this. Good luck.

Comment: @RobertCalhoun is right. Follow the steps in the tutorial to install WSL manually. I had the same problem and by executing steps 1 and 2 I was able to install the distro.

Comment: My WSL also broke at some point and causing docker to not start. Struggled a lot to get it working. What eventually worked, was [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10764#issuecomment-1815485695). 
In short:
1.Navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
2. Look for "WslService" -> Right click on folder icon -> Delete
3. Restart PC
4. Install https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/2.0.5
Might have had something to do with rights, as there were numerous tickets about that, because sometimes I got it working in an admin console.

Comment: For me I have no WslService on the registry. What do I do?